# A value of type 'Iterable<NoteModel>' can't be returned from an async function with return type 'Future<List<NoteModel>?>'

Tags: android, flutter, sqflite

lib/database/database_helper.dart:54:51: Error: The argument type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.

- 'Map' is from 'dart:core'.
  return notes.map((e) => NoteModel.fromMap(e) );
  ^
  lib/database/database_helper.dart:54:22: Error: Method 'map' cannot be called on 'List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>?' because it is potentially null.
- 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
- 'Map' is from 'dart:core'.
  Try calling using ?. instead.
  return notes.map((e) => NoteModel.fromMap(e) );
  ^^^
  lib/database/database_helper.dart:54:22: Error: A value of type 'Iterable' can't be returned from an async function with return type 'Future<List?>'.
- 'Iterable' is from 'dart:core'.
- 'NoteModel' is from 'package:note_sql_db/model/note.dart' ('lib/model/note.dart').
- 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
- 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
  return notes.map((e) => NoteModel.fromMap(e) );
  ^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1070
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 25s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a `.toList()` will solve the problem of `A value of type 'Iterable<NoteModel>' can't be returned from an async function with return type 'Future<List<NoteModel>?>'`.

Please format your question and provide your code.

Answer (score 0):

The argument type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.

lib/database/database_helper.dart:54:46: Error: The argument type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.

- 'Map' is from 'dart:core'.
  notes?.map((e) => NoteModel.fromMap(e).toMap() );

***" This is showing now"***